Elasticsearch search query returning "empty" response using elasticsearch python API
I am using elasticsearch py client in my real time application.
The application performs search query aggregations like "sum of field settledAmount in last 10 days".
Most of queries work without problems. However a tiny percent fail silently returning the following.
{
   "took":0,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{
      "total":0,
      "successful":0,
      "skipped":0,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{
      "total":{
         "value":0,
         "relation":"eq"
      },
      "max_score":0.0,
      "hits":[
         
      ]
   }
}

When the same query is repeated the response is correct containing the aggregations field and the expected value.
{
  "took" : 191,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 756,
    "successful" : 756,
    "skipped" : 632,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "total_settled_amount" : {
      "value" : 0.0
    },
    "unique_customer_count" : {
      "value" : 0
    }
  }
}

I added some retries and it seems to be related with a load problem, since retrying the query without a significant delay (1s) will end in the exact same wrong result.
This is a query example
GET cases-*/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "transactionAnnouncedEvent.transaction.processedAt": {
              "from": "2024-08-29T00:00:00.000Z",
              "to": "2024-08-29T13:46:49.000Z",
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "field1": {
                    "value": "abc",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "caseId"
    ],
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "total_settled_amount": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "settledAmount"
      }
    }
  }
}

What might be the reason of elasticsearch returning such "empty response" instead of a "429 status code?"

So to clarify.
A search request even if it find no docuemnts should not return a 429. It should return 200 with 0 hits.
Something like so:
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 0,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}

As for your aggregation not being displayed ... that's not an expected behaviours.
Could it be a bug ? Or your search query does not contains aggregation ?

There are of course documents in the index. And there are aggregations in the search request. Resending the request works, but not at the first time
